# Win10 Pro: Monitor #2 does not wake up after sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

My secondary dual monitor does not “wake up” after the monitors go to sleep.  The secondary is an older HPw2207h, connected via HDMI to a GeForce GTX 1660 Ti.  The primary is a new Dell, connected via the DP port to the GTX.  It wakes up without any issues. The only way to get the secondary to function after it has gone to sleep is to shut down the computer and restart it.  Switching the connecting ports has no effect. OS is Windows 10 pro.  Drivers for the monitors are Microsoft generic PnP. Not updatable. Computer is Dell XPS 8930.

Comment: I have seen this before and it has always been (for me) a function of the monitor itself. Set the monitor to use a screen saver (black screen) but turn the power saver off and do not use it.

Comment: Sounds like a promising work-around.  But.....the menu for the monitor does have a screen saver option.  It does however have the power saver option, and I have turned it off to see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: correction:  monitor does NOT have a screen saver option.

Comment: You can try leaving it on and then use Windows screen saver

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking about using the Windows screen saver.  I've reset it so that it is on "blank."  And I will set the power saver so that it never shuts down.

Comment: So does my answer suffice for you?

Comment: Thanks, John.  It suffices.  I've experienced inconsistencies though, due to (1) the likelihood that I have not done everything in a consistent manner and (2) as you noted initially, the problem may be due to a function of the monitor itself.  In this case, the problem monitor is my older HPw2207h matching up with my new graphics card, new computer, and new Dell monitor.

Comment: Should I post an answer for you?  Please let me know